# Distance matrix for elements of binary matrix in R

Tags: r, matrix

I have a binary matrix `A` and need to compute the distance between elements:

[image]

where `< , >` is the inner product.

**My attempt for 4 by 4 matrix is below.**

```
n = 4
A <- matrix(c(0,1,1,1, 0,0,1,1, 0,0,0,1, 1,0,0,0), n, n, byrow = TRUE); A
D <- matrix(0,n,n)

for(i in 1:n){
for(j in 1:n){
if(i != j) {
        tmp <- sqrt(max(abs( (A[i,] - A[j,])  %*% A[3,])/n))
        for(k in 1:n){
                 if(k != i && k != j) {
                    tmp_max <- sqrt(max(abs( (A[i,] - A[j,]) %*% A[k,])/n))
                 if(tmp_max > tmp) D[i,j] <- tmp_max
                 } # if 
        } # k
}
} # j
} # i
D
```

The output is the matrix, D:

```
          [,1]      [,2] [,3]      [,4]
[1,] 0.0000000 0.0000000  0.5 0.7071068
[2,] 0.0000000 0.0000000  0.5 0.7071068
[3,] 0.5000000 0.5000000  0.0 0.0000000
[4,] 0.7071068 0.7071068  0.0 0.0000000
```

Expected result is

```
          [,1] [,2] [,3]      [,4]
[1,] 0.0000000 0.5  0.7071068 0.7071068
[2,] 0.5000000 0.0  0.5000000 0.5000000
[3,] 0.7071068 0.5  0.0000000 0.0000000
[4,] 0.7071068 0.5  0.0000000 0.0000000
```

**Question**.

How to calculate the distance matrix correctly?

Comment: Can you explain the calculation of 2 or 3 entries of the matrix?

Comment: *"Expected result is a non-symmetric matrix. "* Can you show your expected output?

Comment: @RonakShah, I added the calculation on the paper. The result is the zero matrix.

Comment: @MauritsEvers, I show the expected output, but for my input matrix it is zero matrix

Comment: Sorry, it is still not clear to me how the calculation is done let's say for `d[1, 1]`. I guess it is `(1st column - 2nd column), (3rd column >= 2nd column * 3rd column)` ? How that comes out to be 0 ?

Comment: @Nick There is a minor mistake in your p&p calculation (it doesn't change the off-diagonal term). For `i = 1, j = 2, k = 3`, the difference `A_i - A_j` is incorrect.

Comment: @MauritsEvers, you are right, I edited the calculation.

Comment: @RonakShah, I have the formula only, I guess that d[i,i] equals 0's.

Comment: I have to say I'm still confused. The sample matrix `A` you give does not match the matrix in your p&p calculation. I think you may have missed a `byrow = T` in the code for `A`. Can you please double-check? In fact it doesn't help that you give an example where the distance matrix is all zero. Could you edit your post to include an example with a non-zero distance matrix? Perhaps give two matrices, one with dimension `n=3` and one with `n=4` including expected outputs.

Comment: @Nick So has this been resolved? If so, consider posting your own answer or deleting the question.

Comment: @MauritsEvers, I have updated the question.

Comment: @Nick There is another mistake in your calculation. Check the entry that gives you `1/sqrt(3)`. You've got the wrong vector for `i=1`. If you correct that, the entry will be zero. Which means that the distance matrix will again be all zeros.

Comment: Nick, I have a feeling that this question is not going anywhere. Unless you can provide better data (I asked for an `n=3` and `n=4` example that gives you a non-zero distance matrix) this is a bit of a waste of time. Perhaps it's best if you delete this question, and think about a **suitable and representative example** with a clear problem statement first.

Comment: @MauritsEvers, I add the example with the non-zero matrix for $n=3$.

Comment: @Nick And I told you there's a mistake in your calculation (please read my comments). If you fix that mistake, the distance matrix will be zero.

Comment: @MauritsEvers, thank you for comment. I add the 4 by 4 example.

Answer (score 1):

The following is a direct translation of your formula for the distance matrix. We use two `sapply` loops.

```
n <- 4
A <- matrix(c(0,1,1,1, 0,0,1,1, 0,0,0,1, 1,0,0,0), n, n, byrow = TRUE)

df <- as.data.frame(A)
sapply(1:nrow(df), function(i)
    sapply(1:nrow(df), function(j)
        sqrt(max(abs((df[, i] - df[, j]) %*% as.matrix(df[, -c(i, j)]) / n)))
    )
)
#          [,1] [,2]      [,3]      [,4]
#[1,] 0.0000000  0.5 0.7071068 0.7071068
#[2,] 0.5000000  0.0 0.5000000 0.5000000
#[3,] 0.7071068  0.5 0.0000000 0.0000000
#[4,] 0.7071068  0.5 0.0000000 0.0000000
```

The result is identical to your expected output.